# Meteor framework performance with lots of subscription based on skip (pagination)

Tags: meteor

From this https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver.

> As of Meteor 0.7.2, we use OplogObserveDriver for most queries. There
>   are a few types of queries that still use PollingObserveDriver:
>
> ...
>
> - Queries specifying the skip option
>
> ...

That means always when you use paging based on `skip`, which is probably always when you need paging mechanism if you have lot of records that user can navigate, it will use that old very non-efficient poll-and-diff algorithm.

It still looks for me that Meteor is good just for some limited sort of apps where just few ppl needs to work together and some realtime changes propagation.

If i will have something as stack overflow, it will be really slow, because each client could be on different page and that means rerun for instance 1000 queries each time new message is added/removed, because meteor can't read from mongo oplog what query with `skip` operator is affected.

I am right?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to paginate not based on skip. Because you have some sort order (otherwise you wouldn't paginate in any meaningful way), you can say something like "give me next 50 items greater than this value based on this sort order`".

Comment: @imslavko: you are right, this will help. Put it as answer, so i can accept.

Comment: You can also change the title of the question to something more related to the `skip` option

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to paginate not based on skip. Because you have some sort order (otherwise you wouldn't paginate in any meaningful way), you can say something like "give me next 50 items greater than this value based on this sort order`".

For example, if you have a pagination query like this:

```
Posts.find({ author: "Nick" }, { sort: { timestamp: -1 }, limit: 50, skip: 200 })
```

you can rewrite it w/o `skip` like this:

```
Posts.find({ author: "Nick", timestamp: { $gt: X } }, { sort: { timestamp: -1 }, limit: 50 })
```

where `X` is the time stamp of the last seen post.

Comment: i was thinking about it and it will be problematic if you have some docs with same timestamp (it could happen) and they are not on the same page.